# Using the RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying folders and making links of those folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218145/displaying-folders-and-making-links-of-those-folders)

I'm trying to create a simple file browser using the RecursiveDirectoryIterator but can't seem to figure it out... Any help please?

```
$cwd = '/path/to/somewhere';
if(isset($_GET['path']) && is_dir($cwd.$_GET['path'])) {
    $cwd .= $_GET['path'];
}

$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($cwd);
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
while($iter->valid()) {
    // skip unwanted directories
    if(!$iter->isDot()) {
        if($iter->isDir()) {
            // output linked directory along with the number of files contained within
            // for example: some_folder (13)
        } else {
            // output direct link to file
        }
    }
    $iter->next();
}
```

Not sure if this is the best approach, but I'm under the impression that the RecursiveDirectoryIterator is faster than both the opendir() and glob() methods.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to figure out ???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SELF_FIRST` and `CHILD_FIRST` as nothing to do with `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` but `RecursiveIteratorIterator`

If you run

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

foreach ( $iterator as $path ) {
    if ($path->isDir()) {
        print($path->__toString() . PHP_EOL);
    } else {
        print($path->__toString() . PHP_EOL);
    }
```

You would get

```
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css\a.css
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css\b.css
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css\c.css
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css\css.php
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css\css.run.php
```

If you change it to `RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST`

```
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css\a.css
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css\b.css
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css\c.css
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css\css.php
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css\css.run.php
...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css
```

Can you see the difference is in the position of the current folder

Comment: @mister martin what exactly is that last comment ??

Comment: "Can you see the difference is in the position of the current folder" refers to the `...\htdocs\lab\stockoverflow\css` folder being processed before or after the children are being processed.

Comment: And how would you get rid of the dot folders (`.`,`..`)? The poster used `$path->isDot()` but this method doesn't exists. I guess you'll manually need to check `!in_array($path->getBasename(), [".",".."])`

Comment: What is that foreach loop actually iterating over? In other words, what type will the $path variable be? I did not see this information in the PHP documentation.