# PHP: RecursiveDirectoryIterator with remote path

Tags: php, https, remote-server

I'm trying to create RecursiveDirectoryIterator with path like 
'https://172.168.3.3/folder' but it always throws failed to open dir: not implemented.

Comment: RecursiveDirectoryIterator works with local file system path not with urls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661885/using-the-recursivedirectoryiterator)

Comment: Any idea what works with urls?

Comment: You can not access other servers files using the url... use a ftp connection instead

Comment: Is the server you're trying to access under your control? The IP looks suspiciously close to a local one. If not, then no; there isn't anything you can do to access it recursively.

Comment: Yes, I can configure it etc. any ideas?

Comment: I really doubt that HTTP has the concept of files and directories. You may want to try other protocols that work on top of HTTP (such as WebDAV) or an entirely different protocol (such as FTP). Or, if it's really your server, just write your own API server using PHP.

Comment: Actually this is a WebDAV folder I'm trying to read...

Comment: PHP does not support WebDav out of the box but [it can be implemented](https://packagist.org/?query=webdav) because it's just a high level protocol on top of HTTP.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you not to create one from scratch. As you can use ready made libraries.

For Ex : You can use **Symfony's Finder Component** in your project.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html

You just have to install it using composer. If you have not used composer yet, give it a try. https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. What I intended was literally $path = 'https://..'; $recursiveDirectoryIterator = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);

Comment: I thought that you are trying to build a helper library